# How to Fix Error: Incompatible Pointer Types Assigning to

Tags: xcode

Let me preface this by saying I'm new so I might not be the best at asking questions but here it goes. I am getting this error when I hit build in XCode with this code.

```
-(IBAction)unwindToRecipeDetails:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{
    ChangeRecipeDetailViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    recipeLabel = source.textView; // error: Incompatible Pointer Types Assigning to UILabel from UITextField
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do. I based the code off of this snippet which works...

```
-(IBAction)unwindToRecipeBook:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
{
    AddRecipeViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    RecipeItem *item = source.recipeItem;
}
```

This is supposed to make `AddRecipeViewController` the data source for the initial `RecipeBook` page when the user navigates backward. I'm trying to implement the same thing for when a user navigates backward from the `ChangeRecipe` page to the `RecipeDetails` page.

Apparently I mixed two different types of code in the error, UILabel and UITextField. I get that they are incompatible but what could I change either one to in order to make it work. It is a little different than what I am basing my code off of in that I don't just want to transfer the same text, I want to change its format as well.

Again, I'm new at this so if anyone needs more information I'll gladly post it. Thanks.

Update 1: Palpatim: Thank you. Your solution worked. So to clarify, in order to transfer text I have to put .text after the initial source. This combines two unlike objects and transfers only text to text. Is this correct? I'm new at coding and am just trying to learn.

Philip Mills: I meant I wanted to change the format of the text when I transfer it from something that is editable like a textview to something static like a label.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're attempting to assign *objects*; what you probably want is to assign the text contained within those objects. Assuming `source.textView` is a UITextView, and that `recipeLabel` is a UILabel, you could assign with `recipeLabel.text = source.textView.text;`

Comment: Could you expand on "I don't just want to transfer the same text, I want to change its format as well"?